# office excel making a CORS Request as cross domain request

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I am trying to make a cross domain request from my excel addin, 
as sugested by here : http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations

i am trying to implement a cors request.
However whenever i try to open my request i get an acces denied error.

the code i use herefor try's to open a connection however here i already get the error

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'url'); //this line gives an acces denied error.
xhr.onload = function(e) {   

    }
xhr.send();
```

Could someone tell me if it is posible to implement a cors request within excel?

The code with ajax gives also an error object

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'remoteurl',
    cache: true, 

    },
    success: function (result) {
        functionAfterLoad(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval("(" +result + ")"))));

    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.error('Error while retrieving funnel HTML', result);
    },

});
```

However when i do a call to :

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: window.location.href ,
    cache: true, 

    },
    success: function (result) {
        functionAfterLoad(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eval("(" +result + ")"))));

    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.error('Error while retrieving funnel HTML', result);
    },

});
```

I do get the html page as a result witouth any error's

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) has some good tips on making CORS requests on the client-side. A lot of CORS setup is done on the server, but assuming that the server is set up to allow your request, you might just need to include `xhr.withCredentials = true;` before your `open` call.

Comment: Hey @leetibbett I get a runtime error with acces denies, even when i add the xhr.withCredentials = true; flag.

Comment: Do your IE settings allow CORS?  See the answer in [this post](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/04d357e2-847d-45af-bc34-f4f265fe1bbb/i-am-getting-access-denied-error-when-using-xmlhttprequest-in-javascript-to-fetch-data-from-database?forum=crmdevelopment) for where to go

Comment: Yes my ie settings allow CORS, however i do not know if the excel webview uses all ie settings?

Comment: Is this what your response error looks like: Origin ms-appx-web://<some-GUID-here> not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Comment: i added a ajax get to my example here i get a an error object containing Error : Acces denied as error text

Comment: Try [using Fiddler as a proxy](http://simplyaprogrammer.com/2013/12/using-fiddler-to-force-web-service-to.html) to see if it's a server-side issue

Comment: No it is not the request does not hit fiddler so i think its blocked by excel lrdy

Comment: I have had the same issue, going from an excel add-in project to a project with Web API in the same VS solution.  The requested url in my ajax request is *http://localhost:53454/Api/Coffees* but application insights records the 'requested url' as *http://localhost:53454/_api/web/lists?$filter=TemplateFeatureId*.  I thought this was odd and may help someone resolve this issue?